# Can't see my "Triggered Send" Data Extension when creating a Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, triggered-send

I am trying to create a Triggered Send in the GUI.  But under Subscriber Management >> "Triggered Send" Data Extensions the Data Extension I created does not appear in the list.

I'm mimicking a TriggeredSend/Data Extension setup that already exists.  I precisely duplicated existing DE's that already exist and DO appear in the list -even so what I create does not appear.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: When you say "precisely duplicated"... does that mean you used the Copy DE functionality?  Or that you did it manually?  Reason:  Triggered Send DE's must be based on a Triggered Send DE Template.  Manually copying, even if the fields are exactly the same, won't do the internal wiring up of the triggering functionality within ET, and they wouldn't show up in a triggered send list.  Using the copy functionality should preserve that functionality.

Comment: No, I manually duplicated it.  What you are saying makes sense about copying the DE.  But the problem is there is no "copy" functionality for Data Extensions.  Am I missing something?

Comment: When you create a new data extension, one of the options should be "create based on a template" or "create based on another data extension".  If you don't see those options, contact your RM or Support and they can get that updated.

Comment: I have since created new Data Extensions based on Data extensions that ARE visible, but once created I STILL don't see the new data extension in the "Triggered Send" Data Extensions field.   Any more ideas?

Comment: Anybody out there have another reason why this Triggered Send Data Extension is not appearing?

Comment: How do I mark  @KellyJAndrews answer as correct?

Comment: Is there a sendable field marked for the missing DEs? For them to be visible 1) they must be based on the triggered send data extension template (made from the template, not just the same fields, they are marked differently internal) 2) They need to be marked as sendable and have a field relating to email address or subscriber key

Answer (score 1):

**Create Triggered Send Data Extension**

For this Marketing Cloud Connect tutorial example, create a dynamic triggered send for new and closed cases using the same email content and triggered send definition.

One triggered send definition and one email can generate two different emails based on the case status.

1. In Marketing Cloud, navigate to **Email Studio.**
2. Under Subscribers, click **Data Extensions**.
3. Click Create.
4. Select Standard Data Extension (Default).
5. Click OK.
6. Select **Create from Template**.
7. Select **TriggeredSendDataExtension**.
8. Click OK.
9. Rename the new data extension. For example, Case Closed Send Email.
10. Click Next.
11. Select Data Retention Policies or accept the default as Off.
12. Click **Next**.
13. Add two new text fields named SObject and RecordId with Nullable
    selected for each.
14. Set Data Type as **Text**.
15. Set Length as **50**.
16. Set Nullable as **Selected**.
17. Under Send Relationship, **select Subscriberkey relates to
    Subscribers on Subscriber Key**.
18. Click **Create**.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_create_triggered_send_data_extension.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

I believe we experienced a similar issue that was identified by ExactTarget as a "bug". I would create a Triggered Send Data Extension via the template but they wouldn't show up in the list of data extensions within the Triggered Send interaction. This has since been resolved on our account - so I'm assuming it has been on yours too.